# Missing things after uppgrade to RN57

Tags: react-native

I have a project made in react-native version 0.55.4. I'm in proccess of migrating this project to react-native 0.57.1. This is going well, but I'm having a little problem with some things that are missing, but only in release version.

In my settings window, I have some fields with their values. Most of field's labels and texts are from i18n RN library. The values are retrieved/stored using redux-persist. This was working fine before migrating. Also, everything works fine in debug version....the problem only occours in release version, but I got no errors in console during release build.
I'm compiling using SDK version 27 (the same I was using before).
[image]

Problem:

[image]

Build platform is windows.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Problem was native-base version 2.8.0. Dowgraded to 2.7.2 and worked again.